# How do I include a search for my custom listview in android studio?

Tags: java, android, listview, listviewitem, addtextchangedlistener

This is from the Main Activity class. I have an arraylist of arrays and need to create a search bar for the listview.

```
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(this, R.layout.list_view, android.R.id.text1, spellList)
    {
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            String[] entry = spellList.get(position);
            TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            text1.setText(entry[0]);
            text2.setText(entry[1]);

            return view;
        }
    };
    wizList.setAdapter(adapter);

    searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

This is the data in an Arraylist of string arrays. Prefered if searched by the spell name.

```
final ArrayList<String[]> spellList;

public WizardDatabase()
{
    spellList = new ArrayList<>();

    spellList.add(new String[] { "Resistance", "Subject gains +1 on saving throws."});
    spellList.add(new String[] { "Acid Splash", "Orb deals 1d3 acid damage."});
    spellList.add(new String[] { "Detech Poison", "Detects poison in one creature or small object."});

public ArrayList<String[]> getList()
{
    return spellList;
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's simple String search only then use the following code

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() > 3) { // it's for performance I've put 3 you can change it 
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The filter doesn't work for my arraylist of string arrays. That's mainly where the problem is.

Comment: @GarryAlcorn then you need to implement your own version of filter

Comment: Would I have to create a custom adapter?

Comment: Yes, you need to create custom array adapter.